# Merge by several variables on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to join two tables by merge, matching 3 common variables in both tables:

- Df1

```
  job         marital month valor
    unemployed   married june   7
    entrepreneur married august 9
```

- Df2

```
 job         marital month valor1
    unemployed   married june   10
    entrepreneur married august 15
```

I´m using that:

```
  df_nuevo=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='month' and 'marital' and 'job', how='left')
```

And I´d want to obtain:

- New df:

```
   job         marital month valor valor1
    unemployed   married june   7    10
    entrepreneur married august 9    15
```

But the record are multiplied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: on=['month','marital','job']

Comment: Could you display the results you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During merges if you don't set the "on" parameter, pandas will use all columns whose names matche between the two dataframes to merge. Something like the following should work:

```
df_nuevo = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')
```

However this can lead to unseen errors if the columns aren't exact matches (example: ' marital', vs 'marital') so it can be more consistent to specify all 3 columns in a list using the `on=['month', 'marital', 'job']` setup that @chris commented.